# Files to array javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php array that I also want my javascript code to use. I don't want to keep having to edit both the php and javascript code all the time to keep the array current.

Is there a way to translate that array to a file and have javascript and php convert that file to an array and read from the file? How do we convert a file lines into an array in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON:

```
<?php

$arr = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's array/object syntax is equal to the json syntax, so you can simply use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) in PHP and echo that, as PHP is run on the server and JavaScript in the browser:

```
var my_nice_js_var = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray) ?>
```

---

Update: to do this in a JS file, call your file `the-file.php` and then add this add the top:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/javascript') ?>
```

Comment: Problem is this is in a .js file. Can't intermix php and js.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.

Some useful links: http://php.net/json, http://www.json.org/js.html, http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json.php